# C# Creating a list that takes user input and after prints the number from the list within a certain value range.(please explain how and why it works)

Tags: c#, list, integer, filtering

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace exercise_69
{
  class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
  
 
   List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
      //creating a list called numbers
    while (true)
      {
     int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     if (input == -1)
        {
      break;
        }
    numbers.Add(input);
      }
    //fills a list called numbers until user enters " -1 "
  
    Console.WriteLine("from where");
    int lownum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      //lowest number to get printed
    Console.WriteLine("where to");
    int highnum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     //highest number to get printed 

    foreach(int number in numbers)
      {
       if(lownum < number || highnum > number)
       {
         Console.WriteLine(numbers);
       }  //trying to filter the numbers and print them 
          
              

      }          
    }
  }
}
```

> Blockquote

the issue i am having is when i run the program the console just tells me this
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]"
so my question is how do i properly filter or remove numbers from a list within a certain value ( not index )

Comment: When you say "remove from list" do you actually want to remove (delete, throw away, permanently destroy), or do you want to just pretend they aren't there for some operation (apply a filter) only to have them reappear for some other operation (apply a different filter) ?

Comment: Indentation and limiting extra whitespace (e.g. extra sequential blank lines) is very important for readability.

Comment: delete the integers from list that are not within the value range i input ( if i input 3 and 7 it should delete all integers under 3 and over 7) and then print out the list with the remaining numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the console just tells me this "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]"

That's because you did this:

```
Console.WriteLine(numbers);
```

`numbers` is a `List<int>`, it's a whole collection of numbers not just a single number. `Console.WriteLine` has many varaitions ("overloads") that know how to do all different kinds of things. It has a [large quantity of specific variations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0) for numbers, strings, etc and there is one variation that's like a "catch-all" - it accepts an `object` which means it can accept pretty much anything in the C# universe. The only thing it does with it, if you do manage to end up using this variation (overload), is call `ToString()` on whatever you passed in, and then print the string it gets back.

Because you passed a `List<int>` in, and Console.WriteLine doesn't have any variation that does anything cool with a List specifically, it means your passed-in List gets treated by the catch-all version of WriteLine; "call ToString on what was passed in and print the result". Because List doesn't have a very specific or interesting `ToString()` of its own, it just inherits a version of `ToString()` from `object`, the most simple root of all things in C#. Object's ToString() doesn't do very much - it just returns the type of the object which, in this case, is a "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]".. and that's why you see what you see in the console

Now that you know why your code is printing the type of the List, because you're passing in a List, can you see how to change it so you're passing in something else (like, e.g. an actual number you want to print) ?

```
Console.WriteLine(numbers);
                  ^^^^^^^ 
           this needs to be something else - can you work out what?
```

Comment: i have no idea what to type instead , but now i atleast understand why console is giving me that "error"

Comment: What's the specification of the assignment? (answer: *prints the number from the list within a certain value range*).. So which variable is that in the code you have written? (hint: it's not `numbers`)

Comment: It should be Console.WriteLine(input); Right? , i just noticed that i wrote "number" instead of "input" everywhere, now it works because its checking the numbers i added to the list instead of something i have no idea why i wrote